# How to use environment variable for .gpg file path in Gradle signing plugin?

Tags: gradle, groovy, environment-variables, digital-signature, gnupg

Following the [documentation here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:signatory_credentials), it says to set your key, password, and keyring filepath in `gradle.properties`:

```
signing.keyId=24875D73
signing.password=secret
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/me/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

but if you want to use environment variables, you could create environment variables named `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_signingKey` and `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_signingPassword` and then use this:

```
signing {
    def signingKey = findProperty("signingKey")
    def signingPassword = findProperty("signingPassword")
    useInMemoryPgpKeys(signingKey, signingPassword)
    sign stuffZip
}
```

I suppose you could use `System.getenv()` if you didn't want to have to use the `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_` prefix for the environment variables.

But this appears to be omitting the filepath of the keyring file. Is there any way I could make that also be an environment variable?

I'm trying to avoid relying on `gradle.properties` because that is already checked into my public Git repo and I'd rather not have to remove that configuration from version control.

Comment: I realize a local file path doesn't really need to be secret, but I feel like it would be sloppy to have as part of the open source. I would also like to control this variable from one place instead of having to copy it into several different projects.